# function parameters are returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with my function syntax, when I call the function and give its two parameters strings the output is always undefined. I don't understand why its doing this, I was also wondering if this could go on the code review part of stack exchange since its bug free. Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function sm(name, location){
  console.log("Hello " + this.name + " from " + this.location);
}

sm("josh", "hawaii");
```

Comment: `this.name` isn't the `name` you passed in the parameter the `this` is referring to the `Window`'s `name` and `location` property. Just use `name` and `location` without the `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `function` parameters **are not properties of the function** so you can't access them with `this` keyword.

And in your function `this` will refer to the global `window` object so the compiler will look for these properties inside the `window` object and will fire an exception if they weren't defined.

Just write:

```
console.log("Hello " + name + " from " + location);
```

**Demo:**

```js
function sm(name, location){
  console.log("Hello " + name + " from " + location);
}

sm("josh", "hawaii");
```

Answer (score 0):

No need using `this`for functional parameters.

```
function sm(name, location){
  console.log("Hello " + name + " from " + location);
}

sm("josh", "hawaii");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sm(name, location){
  console.log("Hello " + name + " from " + location);
}

sm("josh", "hawaii");
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this` here. Just `name` and `location` is enough to refer the variable passed as the function parameter.

```js
function sm(name, location){
  console.log("Hello " + name + " from " + location);
}

sm("josh", "hawaii");
```